# how to perform photo title string matching in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I want to create a dashboard with three variable :year ,month and day and display the image

Each have two values **year:2019,2020. month:Jan,Feb. Day:01,02.**

I have 8 different png picture. the picture name is m01_y19_d01 meaning month:Jan, year:2019,day 01. So the 8 different pictures are

**"m01_y19_01.png","m01_y19_02.png",
"m01_y20_01.png", "m01_y20_02.png" "m02_y19_01.png","m02_y19_02.png","m02_y20_01.png",
"m02_y20_02.png"**

I want to select the year, month , and day in the menu and reflect the corresponding picture in the www folder.

I did write some code and It looks not work well. I hope someone can provide some  good methods.

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  wellPanel(
   
    fluidRow(
     
      
      
      column(3,
             selectInput("Year", "year",c("2019"="2019","2020"="2020"
             ))),
      column(3,
             selectInput("Day", "day",c("01"="01","02"="02"
             ))),
     
      column(3,
             selectInput("Month", "month",c("Jan"="Jan","Feb"="Feb"
             ))))),
   
  
  
  fluidRow(uiOutput(outputId ='imageR1')))
 
 
 
 
server <- function(input, output)
{ 
  
  
  output$imageR1<- renderUI(
    {
      if(input$Month=="Jan") 
      {return(m="m01")}
     
      else if(input$Month=="Feb") 
      {return(m="m02")}
     
      else if(input$Year=="2019")
      {return(m=paste0(m,"_y19"))}
     
      
      else if(input$Year=="2020")
      {return(m=paste0(m,"_y20"))}
     
      
      
      else if(input$Day=="01") 
      {return(m=paste0(m,"_d01"))}
     
      
      else if(input$Day=="02") 
      {return(m=paste0(m,"_d02"))}
     
      
      
        
        
        img(src = paste0(m,".png"), height = 500, width = 500)}
    }   
    
  
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `if` statements to look like this:

```
if(input$Month=="Jan") 
      {m="m01"}
      else if(input$Month=="Feb") 
      {m="m02"}
if(input$Year=="2019")
      {m=paste0(m,"_y19")}
      else if(input$Year=="2020")
      {m=paste0(m,"_y20")}
if(input$Day=="01") 
      {m=paste0(m,"_d01")}
      else if(input$Day=="02") 
      {m=paste0(m,"_d02")}
```

but really you could just do this in one line:

```
m <- format(as.Date(paste(which(substr(month.name,1,3)%in%input$Month),input$Day,input$Year,sep="/"), format="%m/%d/%Y"),"m%m_y%y_%d")
```

This line converts the r constant `month.name` to month names like "Jan","Feb" and finds which number matches that month you have chosen. Then combines with day and year and converts to the date format you're using in the image names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lubridate` package to first create a `date` from your input (you could also use `dateInput` in shiny) and then format the date according your filename:

```
format(ymd(input$Year, input$Month, input$Day), format = "m%Om_y%y_%d.png")
```